# Get categoryname and parentid and change parentid to categoryname

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Sorry for my question, i dont know how to call this question in a simple way.

Lets say, i have a table, and only one table.

```
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | cat_name | cat_desc  | parent_id |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | car      | some desc | null      |
| 2  | foo      | 123       | 1         |
| 3  | bar      | 2345      | null      |
| 4  | android  | hello     | 2         |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I got the result like this.

```
car ---> some desc ---> 
foo ---> 123 ---> 1
bar ---> 2345 --->
android ---> hello ---> 2
```

there is nothing wrong with this results. But im not going to show parent id to user, i want to show the parent id as category name. The result should be like this.

```
car ---> some desc ---> 
foo ---> 123 ---> car
bar ---> 2345 --->
android ---> hello ---> foo
```

is this possible? if yes, please tell me how to do that. if not, please explain why and give me the solution.
thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a self-join of your table to obtain the results you want.  Try this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.cat_name, ' ---> ', t1.cat_desc, ' ---> ', IFNULL(t2.cat_name, ''))
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
```